# Usually vs Normally

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-difference

1) This is the bus I [usually] [normally] take to my house.

2) Is this the bus you [usually] [normally] catch?

In the two sentences above, is there a significant difference in meaning between using ‘normally’ and using ‘usually’? In a conversation between native speakers, ‘normally’ seems to be preferred/more common option. Why is that the case?

Comment: As a matter of purely subjective opinion, 'usually' sounds *very* slightly more formal in register. You may also wish to consider 'typically', which would be clearly more formal and academic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight difference in meaning - the bus I *usually* take is the one I take most frequently, the bus I *normally* take is the one I take unless something out of the ordinary has resulted in a change of plans.  Of course, these are likely to be the same bus and so the expressions are effectively interchangeable.

I would say that I more often use usually.  FWIW I am a native speaker originally from the north east US.

Comment: Agreed.  There is a slight difference in nuance, but since the *usual* practice is also the *normal* practice, the difference is often unimportant.